# Is this 4/4 or 6/8?

Tags: theory, rhythm, time-signatures

I never was much good at working this sort of thing out. Hopefully, a real musician can tell me. Thanks in advance. [Please listen here.](https://youtu.be/3SP-7gtoAqA)

Comment: I can tap in 4s and end at the end of musical phrases.  And I don't hear a steady triplet feel.  I didn't listen to it all but it feels like 4/4.

Comment: Thanks. So you think I'll be ok if I orchestrate in 4/4? That's what I really need to know.

Comment: It sounds "orchestrated" already.  Or are you rearranging it for a different group?

Comment: If you do encounter sections that have a triplet feel you could always (1) change time signature for that section or (2) write quarter triplets over each half note in a measure, etc.  Depending on whether or not it all fits into the same 4/4 tempo I hear in the beginning.

Comment: I was just trying to create a rough guide for the vocalist to sing along to.

Comment: The song is divided into bars of 3 which is making me think that it can't be 4/4.

Comment: I've just been told this question has been put on hold. It's suggested I retitle the question but how I should go about that I've no idea and the help page isn't much help so I'm off to look for another forum. Thanks and bye!

Comment: As for the 3 bar phrase that doesn't bother me.  As for the hold.  I guess they think your question to too vague.  But I think it's a good question.  Perhaps something like what methods do people use to determine the time signature of a song, and how would it apply to this.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely 4/4.  Notate it in 'straight 8s'. PLAY it with a slightly relaxed feel. As so often, notation of the vocal line will be approximate.

Comment: Thanks. The thing that's confusing me is the verse is divided into sections of 3 bars and not 4 as you would expect in a 4/4 song.

Comment: Yes, nice isn't it!    3-bar phrases are not as common as 4-bar ones, but are perfectly OK.   Make sure you listen to what a song DOES, not what you think it OUGHT to do :-)